# Matplotlib Syntax Issue

Tags: matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a simple graph using matplotlib, but nothing is working. I've followed the documentation but it still spits out this regardless of what i do.

```
plt.plot(Time, raw, colour="blue")
^SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Do you have spaces before this line in your code? Since python cares about indents, you might need to make sure that everything lines up with the preceding lines. Once you fix that, you'll probably get a new error about an unrecognized keyword for using colour instead of color, so I think you'll need to change that too.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal, complete, and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# set test data
time = [1, 2, 3]
raw = [3, 2, 1]

plt.plot(time, raw, color="blue")
```

Returns

[image]